# Entity Framework Parent Child Table return immediate children only

Tags: c#, entity-framework, rest, asp.net-web-api2

I have a standard Parent / Child EF model as below

```
public class DataDictionary 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }

    public int? ParentId { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual DataDictionary Parent { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<DataDictionary> Children { get; set; }
}
```

I am exposing this as a REST api via WebApi and currently it will return the complete parent child hierarchy when I GET a node as below.

```
{
"Id": 1,
"Name": "root",
"SegmentKey": null,
"ParentId": null,
"Children": [{
    "Id": 2,
    "Name": "Demographics",
    "SegmentKey": null,
    "ParentId": 1,
    "Children": [{
        "Id": 3,
        "Name": "Gender",
        "ParentId": 2,
        "Children": []
    }, {
        "Id": 4,
        "Name": "Age",
        "ParentId": 2,
        "Children": []
    }, {
        "Id": 5,
        "Name": "Income",
        "ParentId": 2,
        "Children": []
    }]
}, {
    "Id": 6,
    "Name": "Activity",
    "SegmentKey": null,
    "ParentId": 1,
    "Children": [{
        "Id": 7,
        "Name": "Navigation",
        "SegmentKey": null,
        "ParentId": 6,
        "Children": []
    }, {
        "Id": 8,
        "Name": "Behaviour",
        "SegmentKey": null,
        "ParentId": 6,
        "Children": []
    }]
}]
}
```

However I need to get the requested object and the immediate children only to be returned only so that my consumers can build up the visual representation as the user navigates through the data.

UPDATE: Thanks for the comments guys, all looks good taking off the virtual however am struggling with the .Include as I am in an async method where the find returns the object and I have lost the context.  i.e.

```
    [ResponseType(typeof(DataDictionary))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetDataDictionary(int id)
    {
        DataDictionary dataDictionary = await db.DataDictionaries.FindAsync(id);
        if (dataDictionary == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return Ok(dataDictionary);
    }
```

Any help would be gratefully received

Comment: You can disable lazy loading and do eager loading for only 1 level of your children. Can you afford this?

Comment: yes I can - what would I need to do in order to trigger eager loading for only 1 level?

Comment: I think loading it like this: `dbContext.DataDictionaries.Include(x=>x.Children);` should be enough, Include keyword is what makes it be eagerly loaded. I think right now when lazy loading is enabled, serializer goes through each property, causing enumeration for your lazy children collection, which loads them from DB and causes same process to be repeated for each child, making a good old N+1 select problem happen.

Comment: Thanks for this - taking virtual off as Sergio mentioned looks to be good, however I cannot work out how to get the Include statement to populate the children as I am in an async method which finds the parent but I lose context.  - see updated question

Comment: Can you provide code example for the method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For you it happens because of "virtual" keyword that's used in your entity. This keyword enables lazy loading for your collection, so when serializer comes to serializing your children collection, it tries to enumerate this collection, causing it to be loaded from database. After that, each element in this collection is serialized recursively, causing load for each children collection load from the database (with N+1 select problem).

To do what you want you need to:

First, delete `virtual` keyword from your Children property:

```
public class DataDictionary 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }

    public int? ParentId { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual DataDictionary Parent { get; set; }

    public ICollection<DataDictionary> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Second, you need to eagerly load this collection in your controller. This code will cause only 1 level to be loaded for your dataDictionary class instance:

```
[ResponseType(typeof(DataDictionary))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetDataDictionary(int id)
{
    DataDictionary dataDictionary = await db.DataDictionaries
        .Include(x=>x.Children)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x=>x.Id == id);
    if (dataDictionary == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    return Ok(dataDictionary);
 }
```

Don't forget adding `using System.Data.Entity` in the beginning of the file to have access to `.Include()` function.

Also, consider not using Entity Framework entities in your api - better create DTOs, that will allow you to have less dependancy on your DB structure by API - API will have only a subset of fields for EF entity. You will also be able to limit tree depth here, making a child class that does not have Children collection.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Raderick - exactly what I needed.  Agree with your tight vs loose coupling point - I was being lazy :)

Comment: Glad that helped, @MarkRuse :)

Comment: Just for completeness, when I tried the above I got an issue from the include chaining as it IQueryable rather than DbSet (which has the findAsync method).  This solves the issue DataDictionary dataDictionary = await db.DataDictionaries.Include(x => x.Children).SingleOrDefaultAsync(i => i.Id == id);

Comment: @MarkRuse sorry I haven't seen this one, did not check in ide, you are completely right, I will fix the answer accordingly!

Comment: @MarkRuse also keep in mind that SingleOrDefault might be less efficient than FirstOrDefault since it generates `SELECT TOP 2` query, instead of selecting only 1 occurrence, that FirstOrDefault does.

Comment: thanks Raderick - find it strange that EF TOP 2's for SingleOrDefault but I checked and you are right.  Changed to FirstOrDefault

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want that the hole Children list get retrieved, remove the virtual keyword.

And independently program a function to load the first Child.